# MySQL : ALTER ROUTINE, RELOAD privileges given but still access denied

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I am using a master user to create a user and a database with php with the below code.

```
$shellCommand = "mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -proot -e\"GRANT ALL ON my_db.* TO 'user1'@'%'";
```

Following are the steps:

1. create database
2. create user
3. grant privileges(ALL) for user on the created database. (Also flushed privileges)
4. create tables and procedure with the created user(**user1**).

Now in the 4th step I am trying to drop a procedure(**this requires ALTER ROUTINE privilege**) if exists and then create a procedure. However, I get an error *Syntax error or access violation: 1370 alter routine command denied to user*

Comment: solved. syntax error maybe.